# Make 2d mask for 3d array in Numpy

Tags: opencv, numpy, scipy

I have a 3D numpy array `[[[242,122,123],[111,30,12]]]` I want to create a mask for it. for the first array it would be condition 242 > 122+123. Is there a way to do it with numpy where condition? Something like `mask[a > b+c] = 1` where a,b,c are the values from the array.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar in this case mask should be [[0,1]] since 242 > 122+123 is falce but 111 > 30+12 is true. If the first array is M.
Then it seems that mask[M[:,:,0]>M[:,:,1]+M[:,:,2]] = 1 works. But if i want to add additional condition do i use and or do i do something like this mask[cond1, cond2] = 1 or maks[cond1 and cond2] = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess (as to what you want)

```
In [134]: M=np.array([[[242,122,123],[111,30,12]]])
In [135]: M.shape
Out[135]: (1, 2, 3)
In [136]: M[:,:,0]>(M[:,:,1]+M[:,:,2])
Out[136]: array([[False,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [137]: M[_]
Out[137]: array([[111,  30,  12]])
```

Comment: This cave me the idea of what needed to be done.
End result is: "mask[
            (image[:, :, 2] / 255.0 > ar * (image[:, :, 1] / 255.0 + image[:, :, 0] / 255.0)) &
            (
                (image[:, :, 2] / 255.0 - np.maximum(image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 0]) / 255.0) >
                (br * (np.maximum(image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 0]) - np.minimum(image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 0])) / 255.0)
            )
        ] = 255". This cave my program 28.5X speed boost :D